# How can I use the regex_features in my trainning data

Tags: rasa-nlu

How can I use `regex_features` in `json` format?

I have just started using `rasa-nlu`. I have installed and ran the demo successfully - it works well. But I have juest tried by `common_examples`.

```
{"rasa_nlu_data":{"common_examples":[],"regex_features":[{"name":"zipcode","pattern":"[0-9]{5}"},{"name":"greet","pattern":"hello[^\\s]*"}]}}
```

Now I want to know how to use `regex_features` and how does it works. It will be better to have some examples.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation of Rasa [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/training-data-format/#regular-expression-features).
The example is

```
{
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
        "regex_features": [
            {
                "name": "zipcode",
                "pattern": "[0-9]{5}"
            },
            {
                "name": "greet",
                "pattern": "hey[^\\s]*"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the `RegexFeaturizer` [component](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#regexfeaturizer) is part of your NLU pipeline. I further suggest to update to Rasa `1.x` which contains both Rasa Core and NLU, since `rasa_nlu` will not longer be maintained as single package. Also the [Rasa Forum](https://forum.rasa.com) is a good place for getting help on Rasa.